# update a parseObject without retrieving it again - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Using `parse.com` with android, I am retrieving a `parseObject` in a method and I want to update the same exact object in another method without having to retrieve it again. What is the best way to do this?

Here is my attempt:

I tried to save a copy of the object when first retrieved and change this copy and then save this copy using `saveInBackground` method. I highly doubt that this would work. The copy will be saved but the original object won't be saved, so what is the alternative?

method that retrieves the object:

```
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        MyShop = object;
    }
```

method that updates the object:

```
public void OnClick(View arg0){
    MyShop.put("status", false);
    MyShop.saveInBackground();
}
```

Where `MyShop` is a global variable and I want to update the ParseObject object

Comment: you try to any update in your object??

Comment: @RajaPriyan what do you mean?

Comment: you want just update ur object??

Comment: When you say "copy" are you referring to the variable `MyShop` and "original" to the variable `object` ?

Comment: @iForests how parse handles copying objects, are all copies treated as one copy? Do they all get same ID? I mean when a copy is updated is the original object updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that copies of the same `ParseObject` refer to the same object on cloud, meaning if one copy is updated the original copy is updated. It looks like all of them are `reference`s to the same object, maybe because this is `Java`